# Error rendering 'com.atlassian.jira.jira-view-issue-plugin:timetrackingmodule'. Please contact your Jira administrators

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, scriptrunner-for-jira

I have gotten the following error for a Jira issue just after changing the issue components (I have added a new component). As a result, my automation for Jira rule is no longer working.

**Error rendering 'com.atlassian.jira.jira-view-issue-plugin:timetrackingmodule'. Please contact your Jira administrators.**

[image]